# Android Studio: don't build tests when selecting "Make module" or "Make project"

Tags: android, android-studio

On old Android Studios (on some version before Electric Eel 2022.1.1) when selecting "Make module" or "Make Project" Android studio will build only production code (`:assembleDebug`). On newer Android Studio it builds both production code (`:assembleDebug`) but also test code (`:assembleDebugUnitTest` and `:assembleDebugAndroidTest`).

This makes builds longer. And doesn't add any value in some cases. For example for modules that don't have instrumentation tests yet.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio to build only production code (`:assembleDebug`) when selecting "Make module" or "Make Project" command?